# ImageWithThumbnailsField generating empty thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail, webfaction

I'm using an older version of sorl-thumbnail which has the model field ImageWithThumbnailsField.  It works fine on my local dev server, but when I deploy it to Webfaction the thumbnails don't generate anymore.  The file is created but it's empty.  I found this curious message in the log:

```
2011/02/24 11:34:45 [warn] 15817#0: *74567794 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp/0000025310, client: ...
```

I'm guessing that nginx is trying to create the file in a temp folder that it doesn't have permissions to write to.  Any ideas on how to resolve this, by reconfiguring the temp directory perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this by upgrading to the latest sorl-thumbnail code, as well as deleting a custom version of PIL from the webapp's library on WebFaction.  It instead uses the pre-installed version of PIL for my account.  I'm assuming this is the difference.